# Retrieve All RowKeys in a Partition from Azure Table

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I need to retrieve all the RowKeys in a partition from an Azure Table.

I do not know the "type" of data stored, so retrieving all the entities and getting RowKey from there, does not seem to be possible.

I am not interested in the value, just the RowKeys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using .net framework to query the table, you can use `DynamicTableEntity` to query entities of which type is unknown.

```
var tableQuery = new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>().Where(filters);
var tableResult = table.ExecuteQuery(tableQuery);
```

I wrote a simple Storage Table Browser to query from azure storage which you can find on [github](https://github.com/amithegde/AzureTableBrowser).

Answer (score 3):

Using the Azure Storage client SDK  :

```
// Create the filter

string filter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "EnterPartitionKeyHere");

// Set projection to an empty list so you do not retrieve the 
// unnecessary data. Faster retrieval and minimal payload.

TableQuery tableQuery =
       new TableQuery().Where(filter).Select(new List<string>{});

//Execute the query
var result = table.ExecuteQuery(tableQuery);
```

Comment: Explain the reason why you mark down in this case Code Formatting. Not functional. This should solve the question in most efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Table Storage supports something called `Query Projection` using which you can specify the attributes you wish to retrieve instead of retrieving all attributes. You can use that to retrieve just the RowKeys in a partition in a table.

Assuming you're using REST API, your query string would be:

```
?$filter=(PartitionKey eq 'Your PartitionKey')&$select=RowKey
```

You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894031.aspx.